# RSYNC over SSH in Tomato/dd-wrt

Tags: rsync, ssh-tunneling, arm, dd-wrt

I have installed Advanced Tomato ver 3.3-128 on my Asus RT-AC68R/U (ARMv7, 2 core).
Additionally I have Entware installed too. This router is equipped with USBv3 port with 4 TB HDD connected. So I use this router as my home backup unit.
I got possibility to backup this disk on distant server (different geographical location). But the only possibility to connect to this distant server is to use RSYNC over SSH with username/password authentication. No possibility to use only private/public keys because of administrator of this distant server.
I can do it without problems manually, but I want to backup to distant location was done once a day automatically.
The problem I have is to pass password to SSH during establishing connection. In "ordinary" Linux it would be possible to use `sshpass` command, but there is no such command ona my router. Both natively and in Entware as a extension to native list of commands.
I am not to claver to compile `sshpass` from sources. Does anybody can help me automatize establishing connection to distant server over SSH?

Comment: does `opkg update ; opkg install sshpass` help?

Comment: No. There is no sshpass in repository. Maybe You know repo containing SSHPASS for ARM?